# Setting the absolute position of a figure using python matplotlib with the MacOSX backend

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to set the absolute position of a figure on the screen using matplotlib with the MacOSX backend?

This answer

[How do you set the absolute position of figure windows with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449585/how-do-you-set-the-absolute-position-of-figure-windows-with-matplotlib)

says it can be done for other backends, but doesn't mention how to do it with the MacOSX backend.

Answer (score 5):

With the *MacOSX backend* there is no way to set the window position of a matplotlib window. However *under MacOSX* generally speaking you can use other matplotlib backends which allow for this. The `TkAgg` backend (using `Tcl/Tk` via the [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) binding in the Python standard library) should be installed automatically.

In your python script, before anything else, switch to this backend, then create your plot, show it and now you can move the window with

```
get_current_fig_manager().window.wm_geometry("+<x-pos>+<y-pos>")
```

Here a working example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") # set the backend
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot([0,1,2,0,1,2]) # draw something
plt.show(block=False)

plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.wm_geometry("+600+400") # move the window
```

If you install the IMHO nicer [Qt4](https://www.qt.io/) GUI framework with the [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) bindings, then you position the window with

```
get_current_fig_manager().window.setGeometry(<x-pos>,<x-pos>,<width>,<height>)
```

Again the full example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg") # set the backend
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot([0,1,2,0,1,2]) # draw something
plt.show(block=False)

plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.setGeometry(600,400,1000,800)
```

Comment: This solution also works on Windows 8, while original Windows solution from the OP-post link dosen't work with AttributeError: setGeometry (or whatever attribute you use). This probably has something to do with Tkinter versions.

Comment: With my (fairly new) Python (3.8.5, Anaconda) I get that Qt4Agg is deprecated but matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg") works fine.

Comment: Thx @kristjan-jonasson. Yes, the Qt bindings have been updated since 2015…