# How to determine screen size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a general way to get the screen size in pixels using matplotlib with any interactive backend (e.g. TkAgg, Qt4Agg, or macosx).

I am trying to write a function which can open a window at a set of standard locations on the screen like e.g. the right half of the screen, or the top-right corner.

I wrote a working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29039755/3753826), copied below, but it requires one to use full_screen_toggle() (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791519/3753826)) to create a full-screen window to measure its size.

I am looking for a way to get the screen size without creating a full-screen window and then changing its size.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def move_figure(position="top-right"):
    '''
    Move and resize a window to a set of standard positions on the screen.
    Possible positions are:
    top, bottom, left, right, top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right
    '''

    mgr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    mgr.full_screen_toggle()  # primitive but works to get screen size
    py = mgr.canvas.height()
    px = mgr.canvas.width()

    d = 10  # width of the window border in pixels
    if position == "top":
        # x-top-left-corner, y-top-left-corner, x-width, y-width (in pixels)
        mgr.window.setGeometry(d, 4*d, px - 2*d, py/2 - 4*d)
    elif position == "bottom":
        mgr.window.setGeometry(d, py/2 + 5*d, px - 2*d, py/2 - 4*d)
    elif position == "left":
        mgr.window.setGeometry(d, 4*d, px/2 - 2*d, py - 4*d)
    elif position == "right":
        mgr.window.setGeometry(px/2 + d, 4*d, px/2 - 2*d, py - 4*d)
    elif position == "top-left":
        mgr.window.setGeometry(d, 4*d, px/2 - 2*d, py/2 - 4*d)
    elif position == "top-right":
        mgr.window.setGeometry(px/2 + d, 4*d, px/2 - 2*d, py/2 - 4*d)
    elif position == "bottom-left":
        mgr.window.setGeometry(d, py/2 + 5*d, px/2 - 2*d, py/2 - 4*d)
    elif position == "bottom-right":
        mgr.window.setGeometry(px/2 + d, py/2 + 5*d, px/2 - 2*d, py/2 - 4*d)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Usage example for move_figure()

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot([0, 1])
    move_figure("top-right")

    plt.figure(2)
    plt.plot([0, 3])
    move_figure("bottom-right")
```

Comment: Does this SO answer help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python

Comment: re-tagged as the question is not dependent on mpl at all, just on Qt.

Comment: @VidhyaG your solution would work. Thanks. However I am not looking for a Windows-only solution

Comment: @tcaswell if what I try to achieve cannot be done with matplotlib, it would be useful to explain this in an answer. However I am not sure how the solution to my question can be "not dependent on matplotlib at all". Are get_current_fig_manager() and full_screen_toggle() not matplotlib commands? I assume I would have to use different commands if I were using an alternative plotting library like e.g. Chaco. Perhaps I misunderstood... A clarification, and possible directions for the proper solution, if any, would be appreciated.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I thought you were asking specifically about doing this in `Qt`.  I suspect that this is going to be backend dependent.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

This works for TKagg

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

window = plt.get_current_fig_manager().window
screen_x, screen_y = window.wm_maxsize()

#or
screen_y = window.winfo_screenheight()
screen_x = window.winfo_screenwidth()
```

Only odd thing I've seen is sometimes the y size is off by about 22 px.

Comment: The solution using `winfo_screenheight()` gives the proper size without the offset of `wm_maxsize()`

Comment: Yes. That's why I said 'or'.

Comment: Your answer did not state that the "odd thing" only refers to the first solution.

Comment: Is there some reason this isn't being marked as the solution?

Comment: Because it is backend specific. Unfortunately a general solution, which works with any interactive backend, does not seem to exist in matplotlib.

Comment: For dual+ screen setup, both methods here give the total width of both screens.

Answer (score 1):

This works for OS X:

```
import AppKit
[(screen.frame().size.width, screen.frame().size.height) for screen in AppKit.NSScreen.screens()]
```

The Apple document on the [`NSScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/index.html) class.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is also OS-specific.