# programmatically adapt figures to screen size in matplotlib across platforms and backends

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

I can create very nice figures with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
```

often, I need to generate large figures and I do

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(80,60))
```

which is fine, but generates figures that are larger than the screen and need to be manually resized.
This is desired behavior, if I read the documentation I see:

```
figsize
w,h tuple in inches
```

So I have found the sizes of my screen manually, and now it generate nice fullscreen figures.
However, if I change monitor I need to repat this.
How do I find programmtatically the size of the screen in use?

I have found many answers, but they all rely on external libraries or are platform-specific, or back-end specific
**Any solution that I could trasparently use across OS, backends, without adding dependencies to my project?**

[How to determine screen size in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087072/how-to-determine-screen-size-in-matplotlib).

I have tried

```
window = plt.get_current_fig_manager().window
screen_x, screen_y = window.wm_maxsize()
```

but I am seeing the following exception:

> AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'wm_maxsize'

I am using Python 2.7 within Anaconda on Linux, Win 7+ with a automatic graphic backend.

---

UPDATE

It seems that many ways exist

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2015/08/18/getting-your-screen-resolution-with-python/

[How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355364/2666859

However, none of them is platform or backend independent.
Perhaps an alternative is first detect platform and then the backend in use and cascade in a long multicase if with all the particular solutions as cases? 
Apparently, such a chain solution exists
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21213145/4124317

Is this pythonic?Is the best way to go?

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355364/2666859

Comment: Works on the window installation. Later I will try it on Linux. However, I think this is not the complete answer as it says ''depend on your matplotlib backend. For Qt''

Comment: So I was wondering if the screen size could be access by other libs, such as os/sys

Comment: See [this blog](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2015/08/18/getting-your-screen-resolution-with-python/) , and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python) answer

Comment: Thanks. The blog post presents only external libraries/platform dependant solutions

Comment: same applies to the other SO request

Comment: I am adding the links you shared with me to the question

Comment: Even if there was a system independent way of finding out the screen size in python, you would not find it by asking about matplotlib plots. There is already [an answer which implements a chain of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21213145/4124317) and is hence pretty system independent. What else are you expecting to see?

Comment: maybe an undocumented internal function of matplotlib which could do this? matplotlib  must get the screen size somewhere, and I would like to follow that pathway

Comment: I guess there is no universal solution according to very different backends and OS

Comment: Why do you think that "matplotlib must get the screen size somewhere"? This is exactly the purpose of a backend. So yes, each matplotlib backend will be able to determine the screen size or let it be determined by some method (e.g. `showMaximized()` for Qt).

Comment: ok, I was hoping that somewhere, matplotlib would wrap these calls to back-end specific implementations into a showMaximized()

Comment: Basically avoiding to rewrite this chain solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/21213145/4124317

Comment: It is still sounds pretty legit to me as a question. If I need to include the chain of solutions proposed, the largest part of the script will be devoted to open a figure full screen, which is something can be done easily in many languages

Comment: Yes, but those languages clearly define a system to be used. So, once you define the system to be used, this can easily done in two lines of code.