# Python on windows, open plot windows next to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, enthought

I am using EPD-python2.7 on windows7. In my python program I end up creating 4-5 figures in separate plot windows. By default the plot windows get stacked on top of each other. Every time I have to drag and replace each of these windows away and distribute over the screen area.

(Q1) Is there any way to set it automatically to have plot windows created next to each other? As shown below in the attached image (it is the screenshot of my second external screen).

(Q2) I have a second (extra) screen, and ideally I would like to have the plot windows created next to each other the second screen, when every time I run my program[image]

Comment: Lets  say, when I create 5 plots, by default the plot windows are created at the center of the screen and are stacked exactly on top of each other. I wish to have them created next to each other (lets say, starting from top-left).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose the location of your plot but it is dependant on backend. To check this,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

and then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449585/how-do-you-set-the-absolute-position-of-figure-windows-with-matplotlib) answer for various ways to adjust. 
For example, this works for me on linux with `Qt4Agg`,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Choose the correct dimensions for your first screen
FMwidth = 1280
FMheight = 1024

#Choose the correct dimensions for your second screen
SMwidth = 1280
SMheight = 1024

fm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
#Works with QT on linux 
fm.window.setGeometry(FMwidth,0,SMwidth,SMheight)
```

This may be better for windows

```
fm.window.wm_geometry("+500+0")
```

You may also be able to get the screen size(s) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python),

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
weight = GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

You can easily create a counter which increments whenever you create a plot and adjusts this specified position so the next plot is next to the previous one each time. However, the size and layout are much easier if you use subplots, for example to set up your 2 by 3 grid,

```
#Setup 2 by 3 grid of subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,3,figsize=(width,height))

axs[0,0].plot(x, np.sinc(x))
axs[1,0].hist(y)
etc
```

You can then use your counter to specify which plot you are currently using and increment this whenever you plot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question.  What wasn't obvious for me when I looked through the answers is that when you have a second monitor, you can get to it by just using coordinates that are relative to your first monitor.  For example, I have a 4k monitor above my 1080p primary monitor, and I get put figures onto it by using negative values for the y position.

```
mgr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mgr.window.move(-400,-2000)
plt.show()
```

Apparently it knows my monitor arrangement from Windows.