# Matplotlib, how set absolute position of figures.

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two figure window. One is defined

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sctPlot = ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1])
```

the other one is defined as:

```
resultWindow = figure(2, figsize=(8, 8))
```

So how can I set the absolute position of each figure so that when I run the code the two windows does not overlap with each other.

I tried resultWindow.get_manager.setPosition but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set the absolute position of figure windows with matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449585/how-do-you-set-the-absolute-position-of-figure-windows-with-matplotlib)

Comment: Hi Andras, I tried the answer on that thread and it doesn't work.

Comment: please note that "it doesn't work" is never enough information. I suggest updating your question with your attempt, possibly linking to the question explicitly, and specifying *how it doesn't work*.