# Is it possible, that the window with the python plots in vs code shows up at the same spot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I have a python program (not a notebook, a python file) where I produce several plots that show up one after the other. The program looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

functions = [np.sin, np.cos, np.abs, np.square]

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
for func in functions:
    plt.plot(x, func(x))
    plt.show()
```

When I run the program in vscode I have to close one plot before the next one opens. The windows with the plots open at different locations every time and it would be more convenient if the X button was at the same place every time so i can click through them more easily. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: try to determine the matplotlib backend that you use and if you configure it with window pos and size

Comment: I am using TkAgg but I don't know how to configure it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import get_current_fig_manager

functions = [np.sin, np.cos, np.abs, np.square]
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
for func in functions:
    thismanager = get_current_fig_manager()
    thismanager.window.wm_geometry("+500+0")
    plt.plot(x, func(x))
    plt.show()
```

Like on this webpage: https://pyquestions.com/how-do-you-set-the-absolute-position-of-figure-windows-with-matplotlib
or as answered here: [How do you set the absolute position of figure windows with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449585/how-do-you-set-the-absolute-position-of-figure-windows-with-matplotlib).
I thought it was a vscode issue but everything is done by matplotlib. If anyone knows a more permanent solution, please let me know, as setting this for every plot is quite annoying.

Comment: Actually it is probably best to write the two lines right before plt.show()