# PyCharm how to display plot in seperate window on same monitor

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

When i plot something in PyCharm using matplotlib it plots the figure in a seperate window, which is what i want, but it also opens it on the main monitor. Is there a option to open it on my second monitor?

I could not find any similar question (only questions about plotting on the same monitor without a seperate window).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a position in the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mngr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
# to put it into the upper left corner for example:
mngr.window.setGeometry(2000,100,640, 545)
plt.show()
```

Comment: unfortunately does not work.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\5_Python\Pych\main1.py", line 37, in <module>
    mngr.window.setGeometry(2000,100,640, 545)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'setGeometry'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Does the code work by itself? or does it crash in your own implementation?

Comment: Both. It does not work by itself. And also not in my own implementation.

Comment: what matlplotlib version do you have?

Comment: Matplotlib version 3.5.2

Comment: Ok I have the 3.5.1 because I had issue with the new one. that can explain the error

Comment: Version 3.5.1 also produces the same error for me :( I will look further into this error. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Ok i got the code to run with this small change: mngr.window.setGeometry = (2000,100,640, 545).

However, changing the numbers still does not seem to be doing anything

Comment: yes, you have just add a variable named `setGeometry` to the `mngr.window` class. This will have no impact on the window at all. the  `setGeometry()` is a function that does things in it. but it seems that you don"t have the same `FigureManagerBase` object.

Comment: can you `print( type(mngr))` just after `mngr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()`? I get `<class 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt.FigureManagerQT'>`

Comment: Ya there seems to be a difference there: '''<class 'matplotlib.backends._backend_tk.FigureManagerTk'>''' Anyway i have found a working solution in another post. Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Seems like different backend needs different code: this works for me:
mngr.window.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (2200, 100))

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in another post [How do you set the absolute position of figure windows with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449585/how-do-you-set-the-absolute-position-of-figure-windows-with-matplotlib)

```
def move_figure(f, x, y):
    """Move figure's upper left corner to pixel (x, y)"""
    backend = matplotlib.get_backend()
    if backend == 'TkAgg':
        f.canvas.manager.window.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
    elif backend == 'WXAgg':
        f.canvas.manager.window.SetPosition((x, y))
    else:
        # This works for QT and GTK
        # You can also use window.setGeometry
        f.canvas.manager.window.move(x, y)

f, ax = plt.subplots()
move_figure(f, 2200, 500)
plt.show()
```