# What is the matplotlib equivalent of MATLAB Figure.Position?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I am working on converting some MATLAB plotting code to Python / matplotlib.  The original MATLAB code contains this:

```matlab
F = figure;

% ... create subplots and draw on one of them ...

F.Position = [400 80 650 10];
```

I am trying to determine the matplotlib equivalent of the assignment to `F.Position`.

MATLAB docs describe this property as conveying the location and size of the drawable area, but `matplotlib.figure.Figure` does not appear to have a corresponding property.

`matplotlib.axes.Axes` does seem to have such position -- at least two positions, in fact -- but I'm uncertain whether this is the corresponding property, in part because MATLAB Axes also have their own positions.  If this is the right place to look then which `Axes` should be affected?  The current ones?  Those of all subplots? Those of the not-yet-drawn subplots?  Something else? And which of the positions of those `Axes` should be affected?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

**Update:**

I am aware of the matplotlib figure size property. I take the figure offsets expressed in the MATLAB version to be important, so I don't think that adjusting the figure size alone will be adequate.

Comment: Note that the first two numbers specify the location of the bottom-left corner of the window w.r.t. the bottom-left corner of the screen. Units are “pixels” by default, but can be set to anything, make sure you figure out what the [”Units”](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1_sep_shared-Units) are for the figure. A “pixel” is not an actual screen pixel though, beware!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about exactly where on your screen it shows up, then it might be good enough to set the size of the figure:

`fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width,height))`

The default units are inches, but that can be changed: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_size_units.html

If you do care about the position, it looks like it's described in more detail here: [How do you set the absolute position of figure windows with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449585/how-do-you-set-the-absolute-position-of-figure-windows-with-matplotlib)