# How do I tell matplotlib.pyplot to draw the figure on a different display?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am using a laptop (mac os) with two external displays.  When I use `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot anything, the new figure always shows up on the laptop screen.

Is there a programmatic way to have `matplotlib.pyplot` create the figure on a different display (rather than having to manually drag the figure window over to the extended display from the laptop display)?

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37999370/6542361
If not, what's the output of `matplotlib.get_backend()`?

Answer (score 0):

@GandhiGandhi's link led me to a solution.:

```
brew install python-tk
```

then in my code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
plt.imshow(my_data) 
plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.wm_geometry("-6400-1600")
```

where "-6400-1600" are values that work for my particular arrangement of displays (6400 pixel to the left because the display  where I want to appear is two displays to the left of the laptop's display.)

I'm curious if it's possible to specify a specific display, and offsets relative to that display, as opposed to having to empirically determine offsets relative to the primary display as I've done here; but this works for now.